# Is Kama good or bad for life

Tags: kama, purushartha

According to wikipedia article of [Arishadvargas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arishadvargas) it states

> According to the Hindu scriptures, Kama and krodha or lust and anger are responsible for all kinds of difficult experiences which we have in our lives.

And according to purusharth it is one of the goals of life.

So i am confused here. Any explaination would be helpful.

> the question is different because here in wikipedia it says kama is bad for life also where as it is one of the goal.